# Get value of session on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session

I have React app, and server side app.
I created user session at the server side, and I want to get the value of it on React.
How can I do it?

```
const [user,setUser] = useState(null)
```

I want that the initial value will be the session and not null

Answer (score 0):

when you load your app, send an api call to the server and the server will resturn the session id or whatever `res.send(sessionID)`

Comment: can you edit your post with your code ? it would be easier for us to help,if you could see the code. And what you want to accomplish

Comment: I did what you said DadiT,  I made use state that includes user data and then I fetch and set the state to the data from it but the problem about it is that until the fetch done, the app think that the user is not logged in because the state says its null